# A java fatal error when using deepwater with tensorflow

Tags: h2o

An error occurred when running the following code:

```
    model = H2ODeepWaterEstimator(epochs=10, activation="Rectifier", hidden=[200,200],
                          ignore_const_cols=False, mini_batch_size=256,
                          input_dropout_ratio=0.1, hidden_dropout_ratios=[0.5,0.5],
                          stopping_rounds=3, stopping_tolerance=0.05,
                          stopping_metric="misclassification",score_interval=2,
                          score_duty_cycle=0.5,score_training_samples=1000,
                          score_validation_samples=1000, nfolds=5, gpu=True,
                          backend = "tensorflow",
                          seed=1234)
```

The error message is

```
    H2OConnectionError: Local server has died unexpectedly. RIP.
```

The log in that folder shows

```
     JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_161-b12) (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
     Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.161-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
     Problematic frame:
     C  [libtensorflow_jni.so1630a261-826b-43a7-a1e1-8025861cbde7+0x211992d]
```

An answer to a similar question says it occurs when the requirements of deepwater are not met, but I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I believe I have installed cuda, cudnn and tensorflow successfully

```
    zpm@zpm-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500:~$ nvcc -V
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
    Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61

    zpm@zpm-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y500:~$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
    #define CUDNN_MAJOR      5
    #define CUDNN_MINOR      1
    #define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 10

    tensorflow-gpu            1.1.0                     <pip>
```

So how can I fix this error?

By the way I install tensorflow with

```
   pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.1.0
```

I don't know whether it will cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deep Water is a legacy project (as of December 2017), which means that it is no longer under active development. The H2O.ai team has no current plans to add new features, however, contributions from the community (in the form of pull requests) are welcome.

To answer your question, Deepwater was built at the time with a pre-1.0 version of Tensorflow, probably doesn't work with 1.1.0.